# Extract year from title

Tags: r, string, extract

Hello I want to extract the year from the title with dataframe `movies$title` to the dataframe `movies$year` in R.

**Actual:**

```
Title
Movie1(2017)
Movie2(2018)
```

**Expected:**

```
title    year
Movie1   2017
Movie2   2018
```

Sorry for the ugly post, but I can't get it better. I've searched the web incl stackoverflow but cant seem to find the solution. Its for a large dataset of 10.000+ movies. Someone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

A toy dataframe

```
movies<-data.frame(Title=c("Movie1(2017)","Movie2(2018)"))
movies
         Title
1 Movie1(2017)
2 Movie2(2018)
```

Your output:

```
movies$Year<-substr(movies$Title,nchar(as.character(movies$Title))-4,nchar(as.character(movies$Title))-1)
movies$Title<-paste0(substr(movies$Title,1,nchar(as.character(movies$Title))-6))
movies
   Title Year
1 Movie1 2017
2 Movie2 2018
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, but it's for a large dataset of thousands of movies. Will take me long to type all of those :)

Comment: What do you mean? Your data set should already be a df. Is it not? Just use the code given by @terru-theterror and you should be done.

Comment: obviously you do not have to type nothing, adapt the code to work on your dataframe

Comment: Code changed using exactly your nomenclature

Comment: I was wrong indeed about the typing, but the code doesn't get the job done. I want for example: Title: Toy Stories(1995) to be: Title: Toy Stories Year: 1995. You're code gives me Title: Toy Stories(1995) Year: Toy Stories((995))

Comment: Code changed according to this point

Comment: Nice! works perfect now! Thanks a lot for your help and fast responses.

Comment: You are welcome, acceptance of the answer will be welcome.